# Indiana, USA. How do I legally refuse defendant's request for a later trial date and "limited discovery" in small claims court?

Tags: small-claims-court

I filed a small claims case against a small company who broke an item that was shipped to me. In response I recently received a packet of papers from the defendant's attorney basically requesting that I send the defendant's attorney all the things I am going to bring to court as evodence, as well as my and everyone else involved's SSN and driver license numbers (as if I know the relevant store employee's DL # and SSN, and as if I would give them my own). How do legally opt out of or refuse this limited discovery request in favor of presenting all my documents and photos at trial in front of a judge instead? How do I refuse a later trial date as well? I don't have an attorney.

Comment: It's not entirely clear whether this was just a written request from the attorney or a subpoena to release the information to them. If it's just a written request, you should definitely not give them your DL# and SSN. Every attorney will tell you never to give that information to anyone, *including the judge and the court*, unless you are forced to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The general page of information on small claims court in Indiana is [here](http://www.in.gov/judiciary/2710.htm), and the non-legalistic user's guide is [here](http://www.in.gov/judiciary/files/small-claims-manual.pdf). In particular, they say this about "discovery".

> If the Defendant has information which you cannot get and which you
>   need to pursue your claim, you may request that the court order the
>   Defendant to disclose this information to you. The Defendant may also
>   make such a request to the court in order to prepare a defense. Such a
>   request will be granted only if you give good reasons for disclosing
>   the information and only after the other party has been notified of
>   your claim and that the information is being sought. The court may
>   limit the information sought to that which is necessary for the
>   particular case.

If you get an actual order from the court, you cannot legally opt out; but their attorney cannot compel you to to provide any information. If the court deems it important, they might compel you to reveal facts that you know – but not facts that you don't know. This request from the attorney is presumably them giving you notice of the information requested, as required: the court will decide how much of that request is reasonable (especially, relevant – a SS number is almost certainly not relevant to their case).

Likewise, if the court sets a later trial date (perhaps because the defendant successfully requested a continuance), you can request a continuance relative to that, but you can't force them to go with the date you originally scheduled. The basic rule is that each side can request 1 continuance, and there has to be a good reason for the continuance.

Comment: And if they ask for information that you don't have (like "other store's employee DL and SSN") then you don't have to hire a private detective to find out, you can just say that you have no knowledge of this information.